# Is there any point to collecting paintings?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

Is there any value to spending money on paintings in *Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood*?  Some of the paintings are quite expensive (e.g. Raphael's *Self Portrait*) but judging from the bank records they don't appear to pay any dividends.

Comment: No need to get them right away, wait a while till you have so much incoming you don't know what to do with it.

Comment: If you don't buy Raphael's paintings, he will not become famous enough to have a teenage mutant ninja turtle named after him. Do you want that on your conscience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are only for aesthetic reasons, there's no change in the game for collecting them.

Comment: I thought in Brotherhood there was no property?

Comment: I have just double-checked and this is NOT the case in *Brotherhood*.  I bought a painting and my income remained steady at 14,505ƒ.

Comment: @thethinman Brotherhood does have property (remember Brotherhood is the third game), but it is buildings only.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting all the paintings gains you a trophey